# Group Tabs vs Detail View Subpanel Tabs in sugarcrm

Tags: php, sugarcrm

Can the main panel Tabs and Detail View Subpanel Tabs be grouped in different forms in sugarcrm. Means that in the main panel the grouped tabs will contain different modules and in the detail view subpanel the same modules will be grouped in different modules. Is it possible in sugarcrm?

Answer (score 0):

Not without hacking core code.

I did once to ensure that each subpanel had it's own tab... but it breaks upgradability.